# Joomla login problem, repeating the Login denied! account blocked message twice

Tags: php, joomla

If a admin blocking the user in the backend, the users are getting the following error twice.
"Login denied! Your account has either been blocked or you have not activated it yet. Did you not get an activation e-mail and follow the validation link? 
Login denied! Your account has either been blocked or you have not activated it yet. Did you not get an activation e-mail and follow the validation link?"

Comment: give more details. this doesn't happen with clean joomla installation

Answer (score 0):

The problem will happen when redirection is happening more than one time. So check the page on which Joomla Login module is presented, see its menu access rights.